# how i can create index to elastic search using tcp input protocol?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

i have configured logstash 5.5 to use tcp protocol for give the json message.

```
input { 
   tcp {
   port => 9001
   codec => json
   type => "test-tcp-1"
       }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
    index => "logstash-%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
filter{
 json { source => "message" }
}
```

The message has been received from logstash with successfully but elasticsearch not create a index ! Why ?

If use the same configuration with stdin input plugin work fine.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you copy and paste what you see in a debug output, see the link for information on how to configure it, using `rubydebug`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-stdout.html